# What advantage or disadvantage when the craft moves through the axis of rotation?

Tags: launch

Spacecraft typically launch close to the equator along Earth's rotation. This contributes some velocity to the craft. In addition Earth's gravity is weakest along the equator (bar mountainous regions).

[This reply](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/460/288) mentions retrograde, and inclined orbits favour a high latitude launch.

Given the hypothetical scenario where the logistics are suitable, what advantage or disadvantage accrue by launching the craft *through* the axis of rotation i.e at the Geographic South Pole in case of Earth? Would angular velocity still play a role?

What if the situation were reversed - why would one choose to land along the axis of rotation? One situation may be if the Celestial had a very fast rotation - E.g. Jupiter, or elsewhere faster yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only disadvantages, unless you're launching in a retrograde orbit, I'm afraid. And no, angular velocity at the dead center to the axis of rotation (i.e. true axial poles the Earth spins around, not magnetic poles) wouldn't play a role, as there is no angular velocity to speak of. Unless you count no angular velocity as one, of course. Out of my head (I might add a few other points, or describe the ones I'll make better, at a later date tho):

- Gravity is at the poles slightly bigger than the Earth's average surface gravity because of the centrifugal force slightly negating its effect elsewhere, and the most of course at the equator (up to 0.3%), so you'll need more thrust to lift payloads of the same mass. This might not seem much, but it will once you'll have to lower expectations of your clients by up to that amount. Constantly working against margins of error also means this small percentage can fast cascade into a more substantial one.
- No Earth's rotation assist, buying you roughly 1,670 kilometers (1,038 miles) per hour of free velocity at the equator (the radial velocity at which the Earth rotates around its axis there). This is a rough estimate, assuming the Earth was a perfect sphere tho. It isn't and the advantage to the equatorial launches should be even slightly bigger. Prograde launches use this to their advantage for a slight, but important assistance of the Earth's rotation and slightly less atmospheric drag. I.e. your initial velocity relative to the surface is already something, compared to nothing, and you don't get a benefit of moving in the direction the atmosphere rotates (this is blatant oversimplification though, it really depends on many more factors, but on average, it's true).
- Faster exposure to the solar radiation because of the Earth's magnetosphere being the weakest there (and somewhat also at the South Atlantic Anomaly). This might or might not matter though, depending on the tolerance of your onboard and launch equipment.
- It's freezing cold to say the least, which doesn't really help with your work conditions, but it might help keep the pressure in the cryogenic stages a bit more stable. It might. Some of the onboard equipment might also not be expected to work properly during and/or after such atmospheric conditions, if they need active heating by the onboard energy source (which might not be on at the time of the launch operations). Some propellants are also highly cryogenic with exposure to the air in the atmosphere, like e.g. liquid hydrogen (which is already stored in cryogenic temperatures), so subsequently more ice can form on your launch vehicle and cause damage to it (e.g. think - STS Columbia).
- You're launching in the direction more or less perpendicular to the position of pretty much anything of interest in the Solar system, so you'll possibly want to adjust your vector later on anyway. And if you're launching a communications satellite, you'll probably still want to later position it over some population, which tends not to be as dense near true poles.
- Awful weather conditions. You should be prepared to scrub your launch and have a possibly long wait for better conditions due to rough winds, blizzards, fog,... and before your launch vehicle *thaws*. If it would be still in functional order, that is.
- International laws regarding exploitation of the polar regions for commercial purposes and your own pollutants associated with your launch might be against you. Be prepared to have environmental group activists camping at the edge of your launch facility's perimeter at all times. Have plenty of hot tea prepared at all times.
- Half of the year it's daylight, the other half of the year its dark. This is not really a problem for your launch vehicle, but it will make a difference with your crew, technicians, e.t.c. Well rested workers will be less prone to making mistakes, and with multiple hundreds of millions of dollars per launch, you might not want to risk them suffering insomnia, or have other adverse psychological effects due to day/night cycle stretching a whole year.
- Accessibility problems. There's no roads to speak of, and even if you made some, they wouldn't last for very long due to glacial movement. So the only available access is by  sea (you need icebreakers to get there, which is not cheap), or by air. Neither are optimal for sensitive and/or heavy transports.
- Nobody really lives there, except penguins and polar bears (depends at which axial pole you are), so you'll have higher commute costs and abroad working fees. You might also need more security guards with stun and tranquilizer guns. Of course, not being a populated area can be an advantage, tho there are unpopulated areas a lot closer to the equator and large enough for a launch facility.

As for other celestials, the faster they rotate the better actually. At least until they start spinning with big enough velocity to spew their own materials into outer space, reaching escape velocity. You wouldn't want to be anywhere near them, preferably not in the same solar system, if that was the case.

Why would faster radial velocity be good? Because you're approaching them at higher than escape velocities anyway, unless you have enough propellant left aboard to slow yourself down with thrust against your vector (in which case, it would still help you burn less propellant, if it rotated. Remember, you are stopping to zero speed relative to the speed the celestial is rotating). So chances are, you'd want to use aerobraking, and reuse some of the radial momentum to your advantage, landing in the same direction the celestial rotates and have a shallower atmospheric reentry approach vector (which might even save your landing vehicle from disintegrating). The faster it rotates (but below its own escape velocity), the easier this will be. Plus, you save a lot of kinetic potential for the next takeoff, if that's in your schedule at all.

The single advantage to attempting to penetrate a gas giant through the vector following its axis is that their upper atmosphere tends to be somewhat recessed there, so you could hope for a bit longer descent with no weather. Depending on your atmosphere penetrating probe (not a landing at any stretch of imagination, for one, there's nothing to land on, and all the probes we sent so far merely achieved a rather short splash until they imploded due to immense atmospheric pressure, even if their parachutes deployed properly) and its mission, this might or might not be desirable. But probably for the most part, it wouldn't be. Especially, if you're set to study the celestial's weather from within its upper atmosphere. And from above it, there are safer ways to do that anyway.

So these are a few points I could think of, some of them serious drawbacks, some a bit less serious or even an arguable advantage (I wouldn't call it as such, tho), but I'm sure there are many more. :)